# Highlight a point in grouped boxplot in seaborn

Tags: python-3.x

I need to highlight a specific point in each boxplot. For example, I want to highlight the point where petal_width is 0.8 in a boxplot chart for petal_length for each species.

Here is the example:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
##Create three points where petal_width is 0.8 for each species
iris_2 = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length':Series([1,2,3],dtype='float32'), 'sepal_width':Series([1.1,2.1,3.1],dtype='float32'),
                       'petal_length':Series([1,2,3],dtype='float32'), 'petal_width':Series([0.8,0.8,0.8],dtype='float32'),
                       'species':Series(['setosa','versicolor','virginica'])})
iris_all = pd.concat([iris, iris_2]).reset_index(drop = True)

sns.boxplot(x='species', y = 'petal_length', data = iris_all)
sns.regplot(x= iris_all['species'][iris_all['petal_width'] == 0.8],
            y= iris_all['petal_length'][iris_all['petal_width'] == 0.8], scatter=True, fit_reg=False, marker='o',
            scatter_kws={"s": 100})
```

But the code doesn't work. I wonder how I can correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
# Create three points where petal_width is 0.8 for each species
iris_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sepal_length': pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dtype='float32'), 'sepal_width': pd.Series([1.1, 2.1, 3.1], dtype='float32'),
     'petal_length': pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dtype='float32'), 'petal_width': pd.Series([0.8, 0.8, 0.8], dtype='float32'),
     'species': pd.Series(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'])})
iris_all = pd.concat([iris, iris_2]).reset_index(drop=True)

sns.boxplot(x='species', y='petal_length', data=iris_all)
sns.regplot(x=iris_all['species'][(iris_all['petal_width'] > 0.79) & (iris_all['petal_width'] < 0.81)],
            y=iris_all['petal_length'][(iris_all['petal_width'] > 0.79) & (iris_all['petal_width'] < 0.81)],
            color='blue',
            scatter=True, fit_reg=False,
            marker='+',
            scatter_kws={"s": 100})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I ran your code, there is an error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'virginica'.

Comment: it is same code you shared. seaborn library could be outdated on your computer, try updating it. checked again and worked